# Periodically Automatically Alt+Tab

Tags: windows-xp, automation

We've got a Windows XP box hooked up to a large display in our office showing some information.
We'd like it to automatically alt+tab to a different application showing different information every minute or so.

Is there some simple free software out there which can do this for us?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com)!

```
Loop {
    Send {Alt down}{Tab down}{Alt up}{Tab up}
    Sleep 60000 ; wait 60 seconds
}
```